# Slow or delayed loading of my application

Tags: c++, performance, visual-studio-2010, memory-management, windows-7

**Question:**

My question is what will be the impact on my application memory footprint or performance if I replace functions like `foo1` (which I have in my code) below with `foo2`. This function is called frequently in application.

```
#define SIZE 5000

void foo1()
{
   double data[SIZE];
   // ....
}

void foo2()
{
   std::unique_ptr< double[] > data( new double[SIZE] );
   // ....
}
```

**Context:**

My MFC application loads really slow on the embedded device running Windows 7 after implementation of new features/modules. The same application loads fast on PC. At least one of the difference and what I suspect is the cause is RAM on embedded unit is really low, just 768 MB.

I debugged it to find out where does this delay occurs and recorded time stamps within application in loading process. What I discovered was interesting. When I double click the exe, it takes about a minute to record the first time stamp and after that it runs fast, so all the delay is right there.

My theory is that windows is taking all this time to setup the environment for exe and once done, it runs fast. The reason I suspect this is there are a lot big structures declared on stack in the application to the point I had to move some of them to heap to get rid of stack overflow errors even on PC with new features.

What do you think is the cause of the slow or more accurately delayed loading of executable on low RAM machine? Do you think it will fix up if I move all of the big structures from stack to heap?

Comment: What about static and global variables?

Comment: Unfortunately I have globals too but the same goes for them. I am interested in what happens if such big data is declared on stack in functions which are called frequently...does the memory footprint grows!?

Comment: I recommend not using Windows7, or WinCE on an embedded device if you have a performance critical application.

Comment: By start up time, do you mean time before the program appears ready to user, or time until `main` function is reached in code?

Comment: @NeilKirk All the delay occurs before the program enters `main` function which in my MFC app is roughly equivalent to `MyApp::InitInstance()` function. The first thing I do there is take the time stamp which is about 1 minute after I clicked on the exe. After this all the operation speed and times are normal.

Comment: In that case you probably have global variables and classes that have expensive construction costs.

Comment: @NeilKirk I do have large member variables in the `app` class which are essentially like globals because they stay through application and created when `app` is constructed so the delay its member `InitInstance()` could point to that. Do you think moving it to heap will remove the delay?

Comment: I actually don't have any other global but member of `app` class are what I consider global just because they are accessible during the entire span of application.

Comment: What do you mean by "consider global"? I am referring to global variables which are constructed before the main function is reached. Have you tried profiling?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61858/discussion-between-zadane-and-neil-kirk).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are not a lot of things that take a *minute* in modern day computing.  Not on a machine with an embedded version of Windows either.  Not the processor, not the RAM, not the disk.

Except *one*, networking is still based on assumptions that were last valid in the 1980s.  TCP/IP has taken over as the only protocol in common use.  But has a flaw, there is no reasonable way to discover how long a connection attempt *might* take.  So connection timeouts are based on absolute worst-case conditions, trying to hook up to a machine half-way around the world, connected with a modem that needs to spin up the drum to load the program.

The *minimum* timeout on Windows is hard-baked at 45 seconds.  And, in general, a condition that certainly isn't unlikely in an embedded machine.  You might have hooked it up to a network to get it initialized but it isn't connected anymore or the machine you copied from might no longer be powered up.

Chase it down by *first* looking for a disconnected disk drive, very common.  Next use SysInternals' utilities like TcpView to look for network activity, like trying to connect to a CRL server.  Use Process Explorer to find out where the program is stuck.  Mark Russinovich' blog is excellent to show his trouble-shooting strategies using these tools.  Good luck with it.

Comment: My program is a desktop application that drives embedded hardware. It absolutely does nothing with networking. However this delay started to appear after I integrated PoDoFo library to print pdf reports. Maybe it is trying to access network!?

Comment: I unplugged network cable, switched of wifi and than ran the executable on desktop in hope to reproduce the problem there (I do development on desktop and deploy exe to embedded) but it still startup fast without any delay on desktop and I did make sure I can no longer access internet. Your proposition make sense but could this test mean it could be something else? thanks!

Comment: I believe the  Windows TCP/IP stack times out quickly if it knows there is no network.   The case that is bad is when there is an active network that can't actually reach the target.   Does your embedded device have an airplane mode or easy way to disable networking?   Does it have a browser?  You could test how long it takes to timeout a connection to Google.com

Comment: @KC-NH IE returns immediately on embedded unit with message "Internet explorer cannot display the page". Is there anything else I could try to reproduce the long delay with network? Maybe I should try ping...but management doesn't want to address this now its going on back burner for now but I will keep testing this on my own as time allows.

Comment: Does the PoDoFo need a license?  Maybe there is a license manager that retries the connection for up to a minute.  If you have a TCP trace tool, you could check what addresses the embedded device is trying to connect to during startup.

Comment: Like TcpView, as recommended in the post.

Comment: @KC-NH PoDoFo is totally free but that's a good point, I will keep that in mind. I will try to find some time to look into it but its  retiring product and low priority but I am still curious to know why. I am accepting this as answer and update here if I found something. Thanks!